# @Nullable/@NotNull with IntelliJ IDEA, Maven & JSR 305

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, findbugs, jsr305

I really like the code inspection functionalities which are now able with either JSR 305 or Jetbrains' proprietary annotations for IntelliJ.
Unfortunately both implementations (JSR 305 and Jetbrains') do not mix well:

- IntelliJ obviously only understands its own proprietary set of annotations and integrates them quite well.
- Using Findbugs in my Maven Build, it only supports [JSR-305](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) annotations.

The only possible workaround might be to go for [JSR-305](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) and use the [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) plugin in IntelliJ.
Has anybody a better idea? (please don't say change your IDE ;) ).

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Stack Overflow tip: when asking a question specific to a particular programming language, add that language as a tag. (I added the java tag for you.)

Comment: JetBrains annotations are Apache2 license open source (eg org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull/Nullable). As for mixing them with FindBugs see answer below (IntelliJ supports any annotation you define for IDE NotNull/Nullable support)

Answer (score 20):

This has been made possible with the 10.5 of IntelliJ: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/more-flexible-and-configurable-nullublenotnull-annotations/

Answer (score 7):

I'm late to the party, but for future readers this might be interesting.

As of IntelliJ 15.0.2, you may natively use other annotations than the JetBrains ones:

- go to the settings
- go to the `Editor > Inspections` tab
- go to `Java > Probable Bugs > "@NotNull/@Nullable problems"`
- at the end of the options panel (you might need to scroll), there is a `Configure annotations` button, leading to this dialog where you can select from a list of well-known annotations:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As this question is IntelliJ specific it is perhaps best asked on an IntelliJ forum.  You might find this thread interesting http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5262800.  The downside of using Findbugs is that it doesn't provide code injection for runtime checks and JSR-305 doesn't appear likely to be approved anytime soon.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the link. Posted it here because I think it's more than just IntelliJ ;) It seems that once again Java lacks a unified solution. Maybe I'll just patch Findbugs to take Jetbrains annotations into account and switch to JSR-305 once it's approved (if ever).

Answer (score 2):

According to IntelliJ issue [IDEA-64677](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-64677):

- support for arbitrary
  @Nullable/@NotNull annotations should
  be available in IDEA 10.0.3
- there will probably some a manual configuration step(s) to enable support for the non-proprietary annotations (see Anna's comments on that page)