# how to use Intellij annotations in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, annotations

Is there a way we can use the jetbrains annotations @notnull and @nullable in eclipse ? i tried to search for jars online but could not find them. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse does support annotations called `@NonNull`, `@NonNullByDefault` and `@Nullable`

Comment: some of our developers use intellij and some eclipse so do maintain consistency i would need to use intellij annotations

Answer (score 9):

From [the JetBrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/NullableHowTo.pdf):

> These annotations are proprietary ones and included in the bundled JAR. We at JetBrains suggested to include these annotations in the standard Java SDK. The issue is still pending.
>
> Currently the annotations are distributed under the Apache license. The source code is supplied as well.

So, not only you can use them in Eclipse, you can do so without violating some commercial license.  And they're even available in [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/annotations).

However, you may want to read some related questions here on SO:

[@Nullable/@NotNull with IntelliJ IDEA, Maven & JSR 305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468599/nullable-notnull-with-intellij-idea-maven-jsr-305)

Comment: can you give me a link where i can find the jar you are referring to ? thanks

Comment: @user2707760 the Maven repository I linked to contains just the binary jar, [Intellij's source repository](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Source+Repository+Layout) contains the sources

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer, but... I just downloaded 3+GB of stuff just to get 4KB of source code.
Note to others: after you download, the two annotations are in idea/platform/annotations/java8/src/

Comment: @DouglasHeld why didn't you just go to https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/annotations/java8/src/org/jetbrains/annotations ? ;-)

Comment: Because http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Source+Repository+Layout is what you linked in the comment above. But really, thank you as this led me to the information I needed.