# Use of Optional in a map

Tags: java, option-type

Ok before I start explaining my question I want you to know that I know about the design idea behind `Optional` and that it isn't intended to be used in fields or collections, but I have programmed a lot in Kotlin currently and really dislike using `null`.

So I have a Node based editor like in the Unreal Engine and each node has `ConnectionBox`es, which can be either free or are occupied by a `Connection`.

So there are different ways to express this one of which is using a map that maps each `ConnectionBox` to a `Connection` like:

```
Map<ConnectionBox, Connection> connectionEndPoints;
```

and `Connection` could be `null` if the `ConnectionBox` is free. I don't like this, since an other developer doesn't know about the function of this Map and that it may return `null` for an existing `ConnectionBox`.

So I am tempted to use a:

```
Map<ConnectionBox, Optional<Connection>> connectionEndPoints;
```

which displays the intend much better and you can even read it like:
*"This `ConnectionBox` may have a `Connection` attached."*

My question is: Why should I not do this, even though it shows the intend much more clearly and prevents `NPE`s. Every SO-thread and every blog post says this is bad style and even the compiler say that I shouldn't do it with a warning.

---

On request here is a SO-thread that discourages use of `Optional` as a field or Collection value: [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional?rq=1)

And here is the warning (as it turns out it is a warning from IntelliJ):
*Warning: Optional used as type for field {fieldName}*

---

Ok after recommending that the `Connection` reference should lie within the `ConnectioBox` the question just shifts.

Why is:

```
class ConnectionBox {
    Optional<Connection> connection;
    ...
```

worse than

```
class ConnectionBox {
    Connection connection; //may be null
    ...
```

Unless I make a comment you can't see that you may run into a `NPE` and I dislike comments explaining code that could explain itself.

Comment: Why isn't `Connection` a property of `ConnectionBox`, since the latter seems to be a container for the former?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that... probably need more coffee -.- But this still just shifts the question -> why is it recommended to not use `Optional` as a field in `Connection` because the `Optional` still displays the intend much better than having a nullable field (which you can't see when looking at the field).

Comment: Have you considered doing this? `map.getOrDefault(connectionBox, new EmptyConnection())` where empty connection is a null wrapper for connection?

Comment: Could you link some SO-thread or blog post which says this? The warning message itself would be also useful.

Comment: @AshFrench I'd rather use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) because `getOrDefault` creates an instance of `EmptyConnection` even if there's a connection.

Comment: My problem more lies within the readability. When using `Optional` you immediately see that it is **optional**. I know that I can use `computeIfAbsent` to deal with `null` but nobody can see that there is the possibility of `null` when looking at the field.

Comment: You can initialize to your default value rather than being null, or using an Optional.

Comment: You are strongly advised against using a mutable object as the key of a `HashMap`.  Your map will become seriously damaged if the value of the key changes while it is contained by the map.

Comment: @scottb don't worry my `hashCode()` method is overridden and only uses a unique id which is immutable.

Comment: @Jhonny007 the link to the Unreal Engine node editor is broken. Can you find a replacement? I left the link at the bottom of your question as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

After watching Stuart Marks' (who works for the core libraries team in the JDK group at Oracle) talk ["Optional – The Mother of All Bikesheds"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14) from Devoxx 2016, you should jump to [54:04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14&feature=youtu.be&t=54m04s):

> #### Why Not Use Optional in Fields?
>
> - More a style issue than a correctness issue
>
>   - usually there's a better way to model absence of a value
>   - use of Optional in fields often arises from slavish desire to eliminate nullable fields
>   - remember, eliminating nulls isn't a goal of Optional
> - Using Optional in fields...
>
>   - creates another object for every field
>   - introduces a dependent load from memory on every field read
>   - clutters up your code
>   - to what benefit? ability to chain methods?

## Original Post

According to IntelliJ's inspector (Preferences > Editor > Inspections > 'Optional' used as field or parameter type):

> Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result". Using a field with type `java.util.Optional` is also problematic if the class needs to be `Serializable`, which `java.util.Optional` is not.

This also applies to collections in case you have to [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4548816/3429133) them. Furthermore, have a look at these links:

- [Java 8 Optional: What's the Point?](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-whats-point)

  > So to recap - in an attempt to get rid of NullPointerExceptions we have a new class that:
  >
  > - Throws NullPointerExceptions
  > - Can itself be null, causing a NullPointerException
  > - Increases heap size
  > - Makes debugging more difficult
  > - Makes serializing objects, say as an XML or JSON for an external client, much more difficult
- [Why java.util.Optional is broken](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/optional-broken/)

  > The final irony is that by attempting to discourage nulls, the authors of this class have actually encouraged its use. I'm sure there are a few who will be tempted to simply return null from their functions in order to "avoid creating an unnecessary and expensive Optional reference", rather than using the correct types and combinators.

If you care about readability, you could also use `@Nullable` (available in [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_annotations.htm) as well as in [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html)):

```
class ConnectionBox {
    @Nullable
    Connection connection;
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an optional getter:

```
class ConnectionBox {
    Connection connection;
    // ...
    Optional<Connection> getConnection() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure how to use these Annotations. IntelliJ only shows me `com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable` which obviously shouldn't be used as it lies within `sun`. And even if I use IntelliJ's Annotation and someone else uses Eclipse does the code still compile for them? Or for someone who uses Vim can they compile it?

Comment: @Jhonny007 annotations are just like libraries, you can simply import them. For instance, JUnit's infamous `@Test` can be used as soon as the dependency is within your classpath—no matter which IDE/editor. Hence, you can simply [add the JAR to your proect](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/enabling-annotations.html). Regarding Eclipse: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20549153/3429133) post.