# How to create custom-map whose get() call returns Optional wrapped value?

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a map that can hold null values and can return Optional wrapped value.

- I know `HashMap` can have null values, but it will not make it apparent to caller that value can be null.
- The easiest alternative is to use `Map<K, Optional<V>>`, but using `Optional` for data type is not ideal. (Relevant SO post about using `Optional` only for return: [Use of Optional in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176209/use-of-optional-in-a-map))
- I couldn't extend `HashMap` class very well with its `entrySet()` method still facing the same null value issue, so I wrote my class that wraps `HashMap` and has `get()` and custom `Entry.getValue()` that returns `Optional` wrapped value. (still figuring out how to write a version of `Collectors.toMap` for this class)
- The problem now is the class is not easily "replaceable" with `Map`(not programming to interface) and a custom-not-much-extensible-map is circulating in my business logic that I am slightly uncomfortable with.

```
public class CustomMap<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map;

    public CustomMap() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Optional<V> get(@NonNull final K k) {    // Lombok.NonNull
        return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(k));
    }

    public void put(@NonNull final K k, @Nullable final V v) {
        map.put(k, v);
    }

    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new Entry(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(toImmutableSet());
    }

    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    public static class Entry<K, V> {
        private final K k;
        private final V v;

        public Entry(K k, V v) {
            this.k = k;
            this.v = v;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return k;
        }

        public Optional<V> getValue() {
            return Optional.ofNullable(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Expectation: `customMap.get(K)` should return `Optional` wrapped object and `customMap.put(K, V)` should not need to take `Optional<V>` as input. `CustomMap` should be able to act as `Map`.

There should be cleaner and extensible way to achieve this and I feel I am missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could define that behavior as a static method in some MapUtils class:             
public static <K, V> Optional<V> optionalGet(Map<K, V> elements, K key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(elements.get(key));
}

Comment: It is not going to be a drop-in-replacement for `Map<K,V>`, because that interface says that you have to return a `V` from `get`, not an `Optional<V>`. So a static helper method that all your `get` callers can use is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make the use of Optionals apparent and you are reluctant to roll out some custom map implementation that deviates from the Map implementation; this conflicts with your statement that the Optional datatype is not ideal.

Assuming that you just do not want to store Optional instances in a map, a possible solution would be an Map implementation that wraps an (inner) `Map<K,V>` with null values as a `Map<K, Optional<V>>`, such as

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class OptionalMap<K, V> implements Map<K, Optional<V>> {
    private final Map<K, V> map;

    public OptionalMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return map.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof Optional)) {
            return false;
        }

        return map.containsValue(((Optional<?>)value).get());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, Optional<V>>> entrySet() {
        return
                map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, Optional<V>>(e.getKey(), Optional.ofNullable(e.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), Collections::unmodifiableSet));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<V> get(Object key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return map.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<V> put(K key, Optional<V> value) {
        final Optional<V> previous = Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key));
        map.put(key, value.orElse(null));
        return previous;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends Optional<V>> other) {
        Map<K, V> unwrappedMap =
            other.entrySet().stream()
            .<Entry<K, V>>map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().orElse(null)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

        map.putAll(unwrappedMap);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<V> remove(Object key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(map.remove(key));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Optional<V>> values() {
        return
                map.values().stream()
                .map(e -> Optional.ofNullable(e))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
    }
}
```

Comment: "this conflicts with your statement that the Optional datatype is not ideal." -> Clarified about `Optional` in the question; I want it as return datatype.

Thank you for taking your time to implement the whole `Map` interface. I truly didn't want you to implement it on behalf of me.

Comment: `Map<K, Optional<V>> map = new OptionalMap<K, V>();`

The custom map needs to be declared like this which breaks polymorphism. Added clearer expectation in my question. 

Thank you again for answering. I think I'm hitting Java's limitation about overriding `get()` behavior to return `Optional` object and probably it is not possible in Java.

Comment: And also, `OptionalMap.put(K, Optional<V>)` requires `Optional` wrapped `V` which is not ideal `Optional` usage.